# How to check empty row from csv column using PowerShell

Tags: powershell, csv, powershell-4.0, read.csv

I've mixed data(some row are empty) like this in my csv column called "Exchange Mailboxes".

```
Exchange Mailboxes
Include:[john.doe@outlook.com] 
Include:[david.smith@outlook.com]

Include:[kevin.love@outlook.com]
```

I'm try to check if the row is empty first. If it's empty then just assigned empty string for those row. If a particular csv row is not empty then get their Name and Id using EXOMailbox.

Another word will be, how do I skip an empty rows?

I tried it like this but some reason it's not working.

```
$importFile = Import-Csv -Path "C:\AuditLogSearch\Dis\Modified-Audit-Log-Records.csv"

 foreach ($csvFile in $importFile){
    if([string]::IsNullOrEmpty($csvFile.'Exchange Mailboxes')){

      $userName = ""
      $userId = ""

    }else{
      $exoMailbox = $csvFile.'Exchange Mailboxes'.Split([char[]]@('[', ']'))[1]
      $exoUser = Get-EXOMailbox -Filter "PrimarySmtpAddress -eq  '$exoMailbox'"

      $userName = $exoUser.DisplayName
      $userId = $exoUser.Identity

    }

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to exclude rows that have an empty `Exchange Mailboxes` column value:

```bash
$importFile = 
  Import-Csv "C:\AuditLogSearch\Dis\Modified-Audit-Log-Records.csv" |
  Where-Object 'Exchange Mailboxes' -ne ''
```

If you want to exclude rows where *all* columns are empty (which would also work with your (atypical) *single*-column CSV):

```bash
$importFile = 
  Import-Csv "C:\AuditLogSearch\Dis\Modified-Audit-Log-Records.csv" |
  Where-Object { -join $_.psobject.Properties.Value }
```

Note:

- [`Import-Csv`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/import-csv) parses a CSV file's rows into `[pscustomobject]` instances whose properties reflect the CSV's column values invariably *as strings*.
- `$_.psobject.Properties.Value` uses the [intrinsic `.psobject` property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Intrinsic_Members#psobject) to reflect on all properties of an object, and `.Properties.Value` returns all property values.

  - The unary form of the [`-join`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Join) operator directly concatenates all - by definition *string* - values and returns the result as a single string.
  - Thus, if *all* column values are empty, the result is the *empty string* (`''`); otherwise, the string is *non-empty*.
- [`Where-Object`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/where-object), when given a [*script block*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Script_Blocks) (`{ ... }`), implicitly coerces its output to `[bool]` (`$true` or `$false`); in PowerShell, converting any *non-empty* string to `[bool]` yields `$true`, whereas the *empty string* yields `$false`.

---

Applying the above in combination with extracting just the email addresses from the `Exchange Mailboxes` column values:

```bash
$emailAddresses = 
  Import-Csv "C:\AuditLogSearch\Dis\Modified-Audit-Log-Records.csv" |
  Where-Object { -join $_.psobject.Properties.Value } |
  ForEach-Object { ($_.'Exchange Mailboxes' -split '[][]')[1] }
```

With your sample input, outputting `$emailAddresses` then yields:

```
john.doe@outlook.com
david.smith@outlook.com
kevin.love@outlook.com
```

Applied to what I presume was the intent of your original code:

```bash
$customObjects = 
  Import-Csv "C:\AuditLogSearch\Dis\Modified-Audit-Log-Records.csv" |
  Where-Object { -join $_.psobject.Properties.Value } |
  ForEach-Object { 
    $exoMailbox = ($_.'Exchange Mailboxes' -split '[][]')[1]
    $exoUser = Get-EXOMailbox -Filter "PrimarySmtpAddress -eq  '$exoMailbox'"
    # Construct and output a custom object with the properties of interest.
    [pscustomobject] @{  
      UserName = $exoUser.DisplayName
      UserId = $exoUser.Identity
    }
  }
```